# fibonacci series assembly language program -segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, fibonacci

Following is the assembly language code I wrote to calculate fibonacci series (it does not print anything yet). When I compile it using nasm in ubuntu, it shows segmentation fault (core dumped) error. Please help.

```
section .text
   global _start        

_start:                 

mov eax , 0         ;move value 0 to register eax
mov ebx , 1         ;move value 1 to register ebx
mov ecx , 1         ;move value 1 to register ecx
mov edx , 10        ;move value 10 to register edx

loop:               ;start of loop
mov ebx, ecx        ;move contents of ecx into ebx
add ebx, eax        ;add contents of eax into ebx
mov ecx, eax        ;move contents of eax into ecx
dec edx             ;decrement counter register edx
cmp edx, 0          ;compare counter edx to 0
jne loop            ;jump back into loop unless counter equals 0
```

Comment: What do you think your program does when the counter equals 0?

Comment: You forgot to terminate the program so it falls off into uninitialized memory and will eventually fault. Use the exit syscall. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: can you plz tell me what is the exit syscall  exactly that i shall use?

Comment: `mov eax, 1; int 0x80` for example.

Comment: @Jester Thanks a lot

Comment: The comments in your code are less than useless. We already know that `mov edx, 10` puts the value `10` into the `edx` register. It would be much better to tell us what the code does. For example, `;Initialize counter` Similarly, tell us what each register is used for. Not only does it help other people read the code, it'll help you understand why your algorithm doesn't work. (Hint: the value of `eax` is always 0.)